# necessary kernel module files for beaglebone black

Tags: beagleboneblack

How to compile the necessary kernel module file for beaglebone black? What are the compiled kernel files to copy to the target?
make modules_install INSTALL_MOD_PATH=$TARGETDIR generated huge number of files

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cross compile to build the kernel, you can use this inside your linux kernel downloaded files

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- modules
```